# how to create vue-shepperd component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to develop guided tour with shepherd: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-shepherd but I cannot get the element. So here is my component for guide tour:

```html
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { useShepherd } from 'vue-shepherd';

export default {
  props: {
    element: {
      required: true,
    },

    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },

    title: {
      type: String,
    },

    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    position: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.tour.start();
  },  

  data() {
    return {
      tour: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    createTour() {
      this.tour = useShepherd({
        useModalOverlay: true,
      });

      this.tour.addStep({
        title: this.title,
        text: this.text,
        attachTo: { element: this.element, on: this.position },
        buttons: [
          {
            action() {
              return this.back();
            },
            classes: 'shepherd-button-secondary',
            text: 'Back',
          },
          {
            action() {
              return this.next();
            },
            text: 'Next',
          },
        ],
        id: this.id,
      });

      this.tour.start();
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.createTour();
  },
};
</script>
```

and here is my parent component:

```html
<button ref="button">
  Click
</button>
<guide :element="element" :title="'Tour'" :text="'Example'" :position="'bottom'" :id="1" />
```

and the mounted of the parent element:

```js
mounted() {
  this.element = this.$refs.button;
},
```

but the tour doesnt attach the the button element. it just appears in the middle of the page. Why do you think it is?

Comment: Did you tried that way? https://github.com/shipshapecode/vue-shepherd#option-api

Comment: yes, I cannot pass the parent element to the child I think. Thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a usage problem in vue hooks. The child component's hooks fire before the parent component's hooks. Therefore, at the time of the creation of the tour, the element does not exist. Vue-shepherd does not use vue reactivity.

Use

```
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.createTour();
    });
  },
```

[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-glade-figfd3?file=/src/components/guid.vue:1098-1217)

But it's better to change the component structure. If you are using vue3 you can use my [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-directive-shepherd)

In this case it will look like this

```
<template>
  <button v-tour-step:1="step1">
    Click
  </button>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, inject, onMounted } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const tour = inject("myTour");
    onMounted(() => {
      tour.start();
    });
    const step1 = {
    /* your step options */
    }
    return {
      step1,
    };
 }
});
</script>
```