# How to get parent component's ref in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I want to pass button element to the child component using `refs`.

```html
<button ref="button">
  Button
</button>
<child :element="$refs.button" />
```

But in child component element prop comes `null`. How can I send button element to the child component ?

Comment: What you're doing wrong, is not sharing the code... :P

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: You are not supposed to pass a ref as a prop. What are you trying to achieve here? Do you really need a ref?

Comment: Like @kissu asked, what do you wish to achieve? the button itself or some property of it?

Comment: I would like to send button element to the child component

Comment: What for? Please expand on the final goal so that we avoid a XY problem. There are quite a few ways to not rely on DOM manipulation on Vue (last resort pretty much).

Comment: I created guided tour component and I want to use the button element there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343358/how-to-create-vue-shepperd-component

Comment: I recommend that you try to set it up globally as I've suggested.

Comment: But I want to use this component in several places. If I use it in global how can I use somewhere else?

Comment: A global component is something that you can use wherever you want tbh. The opposite is a local component (that you're doing with a local import).

Comment: but even if I use global component, it doesnt change how to get the element of parent

Comment: Why would you need something like passing up/down something if it's global? You can use it in the desired component.

Comment: I didnt get your answer sorry. Would be appreaciated if you can give an example

Comment: @World'sfamouspeople As per my understanding, You want to use the button element in multiple components. You can make button itself as a separate component and use it where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to use the button element in multiple components. You can make button itself as a separate component and use it where ever you want.

You can try something like this **:**

```js
Vue.component('customBtn', {
  props: ['buttontext'],
  template: '<button>{{ buttontext }}</button>'
});

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<custom-btn buttontext="This is a child button"></custom-btn>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-btn buttontext="This is a parent button">
  </custom-btn>
  <child></child>
</div>
```